# Pyserial read in thread cuts off data

Tags: python, multithreading, python-multithreading, pyserial

I'm trying to read serial data from a radio module through a thread (I'm using threading because I want to give user input and make a GUI in the future). This code is just for testing.

```
def read_data(dataQueue,ser):
    while True:
        n = ser.inWaiting()
        if n:
            data = ser.read(n)
            print(data)
            dataQueue.put(data)
            sleep(0.1)

def main():
    ser = serial.Serial(port='COM7',baudrate=19200, timeout=0.5)
    dataQueue = queue.Queue()
    dataThread = threading.Thread(target=read_data, args=(dataQueue,ser,), daemon=True)
    dataThread.start()
    confirm_computer_has_recieved = False
    send = False
    message = ''
    decoded = ''
    confirm_mcu_has_received = True
    sending("lap send", ser)
    sleep(1)
    while True:
        try:
            if keyboard.is_pressed('shift'):
                print("\n")
                input_str = input()
                print("sending "+input_str)
                sending(input_str,ser)
        except:
            pass
        if (dataQueue.qsize() > 0):
            decoded = Radio_decode(dataQueue.get())
            #print(decoded)
            if confirm_mcu_has_received:
                if decoded == 'confirmed':
                    print("was confirmed")
                    confirm_mcu_has_received = False
        if confirm_computer_has_recieved:
            print("confirmed we recieved")
            sending("confirmed",ser)
            sleep(1.2)
            confirm_computer_has_recieved = False
            send = True
        elif decoded == 'boat send':
            decoded = ''
            confirm_computer_has_recieved = True
        elif send:
            # sending("lap send", ser)
            sleep(1)
            sending("lap send", ser)
            print("sent data")
            sleep(1)
            send = False
            confirm_mcu_has_received = True
        sleep(1)
```

A version of this without threading worked before. The issue is in the thread defined by the read_data() function. When I send messages to the computer at about once per second, the output gets chopped up and incorrect. The correct data is:

```
b'\x14D$HxV4\x12\x01\x00 confirmed\x00'
```

but over multiple sends it looks like this:

```
b'\x14D$HxV4\x12\x01\x00 con'
b'firmed\x00'
b'\x14D$HxV4\x12\x01\x00 confirmed\x00'
b'\x14D$HxV4\x12\x01\x00 co'
b'nfirmed\x00'
b'\x14'
b'D$HxV4\x12\x01\x00 confirmed\x00'
b'\x14D$HxV4\x12\x01\x00 c'
b'onfirmed\x00'
b'\x14D$HxV4\x12\x01\x00 confirmed\x00'
b'\x14D'
b'$HxV4\x12\x01\x00 confirmed\x00'
b'\x14D$HxV4\x12\x01\x00 confirmed\x00'
b'\x14D$HxV4\x12\x01\x00 '
b'confirmed\x00'
```

This looks like reads are getting interrupted due to the threads but online it said python serial is thread-safe so I am a little confused.

Comment: Well, there are now guarantees that you will get a full message when reading serial data. You may have to read multiple times for that. Therefore you need some kind of higher layer protocol to ensure that you have received the whole message. Either that the message is of a known length or have a certain termination or something. This means that the behavior you see with your threaded version is within spec and is thus not breaking any thread safety promisses.

Comment: There are *no* guarantees...